# How to use mapKeys() from lodash library in redux reducers

Tags: redux, lodash

I am trying to use **_.mapKeys()** function from **"lodash"** library to map the "id" of an object as the "key" for that object in my **reducer** in redux. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
return { ...state, _.mapKeys(action.payload,'id') };
```

But I get an error as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: lodash_error]

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use:

```
return { ...state, ...(_.mapKeys(action.payload,'id')) };
```

That is because `_.mapKeys` returns an object and what happens is

```
return { ...state, {} }
```

which is not a valid syntax.